# Vertex with MySQLPool giving error 'AnnotatedConnectException -> finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused:' in Java application

Tags: vertex, java-17

We are using vertex Mysql pool to connect with MySQL DB and trying to fetch the data in java application with Java17. Sometime It giving us the below errors:

***1. AnnotatedConnectException -> finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused:<DB_URL>

2. Exception="io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException"***

**Having below configuration:**
Vertex version: "4.3.5"
mysqlDriver Version: "8.0.31"
nettyNativeEpoll Version: "4.1.92.Final"

**Using below code to configure MySQLPool:**

```
    final var connectOptions = new MySQLConnectOptions()
            .setPort(dat1Config.getPort())
            .setHost(dat1Config.getHost())
            .setDatabase(dat1Config.getDatabaseName())
            .setUser(dat1Config.getUserName())
            .setPassword(dat1Config.getPassword())
            .setCachePreparedStatements(true)
            .setReconnectAttempts(2)
            .setReconnectInterval(500)
            .setIdleTimeout(5)
            .setIdleTimeoutUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    final var poolOptions = new PoolOptions()
            .setMaxSize(5);

    this.mysqlPool = MySQLPool.pool(vertx, connectOptions.setPipeliningLimit(16), poolOptions);
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve the issue mentioned above.